# React error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have checked for 2 hooks violations, I have the same version of react and react-dom, and have no duplicate copy of react. I am unable to understand what the error is actually?

> index.js:3221 Uncaught Invariant Violation: **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**.
>   This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have a set of filters that i want to show to user :

```
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Text from "@material-ui/core/text";

function RenderFilter(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <RenderHeader />
      <RenderX {...props} />
      <RenderSomething {...props} />
    </Fragment>
  );


function RenderSomething(props) {
  const { filters } = props;
  const allowedKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return (
    <div>
      {allowedKeys.map((item, index) => (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              margin: "8px 0px"
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ borderBottom: "1px #f6f6f6" }}>
              <div style={{ maxWidth: 200 }}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
              </div>
              <div>
                {filters[item].map(ele => (
                  <Chip key={`${ele}`} color="primary" label={`${ele}`} />
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the essential part of the code where it is happening? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the question, can u please check ?>

Comment: Can you show the code, where you are loading this(renderSomething) component as well? Also, as it a component, renderSomething should start with a capital, something like this RenderSomething.

Comment: I agree with Nayan shah. You must be using it in the wrong way. renderSomething should be a component. It's how React hook works. You must be using it as a function.

Comment: I get your point , i have added the needful source code, can you please refer it .  So I have  a filter component , and all other sub-components like RenderSomething, RenderX are defined as functions and used in the main RenderFilter component